# EventHandler with FormClosingEventArgs - C#

Tags: c#, forms, events, eventargs

I have this closing form code in my Form.cs

```
public void label7_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else { 
            Application.Exit(); 
        }
    }
```

and this code in my Form.designer.cs

```
this.label7.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label7_Click);
```

However it keeps showing error

> "No overload for 'label7_Click' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'"

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems label7_Click method dose not exist

```
  this.label7.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label7_Click);

    void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        //
    }
    else { 
        Application.Exit(); 
    }
    }
```

No overload for 'label7_Click' matches delegate

```
public void label7_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)//this method de is incorrect
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. Users click on label7 when they want to exit the application? The Click event that you are subscribing to does not provide FormClosingEventArgs when it is raised. The Click is an EventHandler event, which means it provides an EventArgs object when it's raised. There is no Cancel property in the EventArgs class.

Answer (score 1):

Event with `FormClosingEventArgs` is only suitable for `Form.FormClosing` event. Change your code to this:

```
public void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Close(); //this closes the form
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set an event handler for a FormClosing event to the click event of a label.
The two events have different signatures and thus are incompatible.

```
label_click(object sender, EventArgs e)

MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```

If your intention is to close the application when the user clicks on the label then you need to change your event handler to

```
label_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirmation", 
                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

if your intention is to ask for a confirmation whenever the user tries to exit the application then you need to add a FormClosing event handler to your form and then write

```
 MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     // NOTE, you don't want to abort closing when Windows shutdown, right?
     if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
     {
         if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirmation", 
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == 
                            DialogResult.No)
         {
              e.Cancel = true;
         }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare bool clickStr public bool clicKStr = true;

```
private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   clicKStr = false;
   this.Close();
}

private void BeforeFormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = clickStr;
}
```

if you click lable7 it will send false to FormClosingEventArgs and set cancel to false.